Checking for presence in database and then adding element in Entity Framework causes unique PK error
I have the following code:
foreach (var species in list.Species.ToList())
{
     if (context.Species.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PK_Species == species.PK_Species) == null)
     {
         context.Species.Add(species);
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}

I keep getting a species (G_$DK0UDIO3OJ) that goes through this and dies on the SaveChanges call with a "unique constraint" failure.
Most of the time, it works perfectly fine, but on a random one, it keeps failing. Does anyone have any ideas why?
I have tried with .AsNoTracking() as a wild guess and it didn't make a difference.

You may have a unique index on another column?

We don't and the error specially says the error is Species.PK_Species.  Thanks for the idea though!

Do u have other parallel tools that are working on the same table? Because maybe your "PK_Species" was already inserted in DB between the actions "FirstOrDefault" and "SaveChanges".

Another good idea but there aren't any parallel actions. I have done various experiments and tried to "find" the species with other fields and the program just doesn't find it in the database.

The main thing is to handle the exception. Any sequence of events could participate in a race condition where a state is True at one point, but False by the time you reach a line of code that is dependent on that state. One detail to reduce that window is to query as efficiently as possible. For instance:
foreach (var species in list.Species.ToList())
{
     if (!context.Species.Any(x => x.PK_Species == species.PK_Species))
     {
         context.Species.Add(species);
         context.SaveChanges();
     }
}

Doing a .FirstOrDefault() involves EF building a query to load an entire row, and attempting to load any existing row into memory. .Any() will boil down to a faster EXISTS check.
Next, when performing several atomic operations you should consider scoping the DbContext rather than calling .SaveChanges() multiple times. This makes it easier to handle exceptional cases. Commonly I would recommend a DbContextFactory class or a unit of work DbContextScope. In situations where you are saving multiple related rows in various locations where you want to commit or rollback as a unit of work, perform those inserts etc. against a single .SaveChanges() call.
foreach (var species in list.Species.ToList())
{
    try
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.Create(); //Factory created instance for this one operation.
        if (context.Species.Any(x => x.PK_Species == species.PK_Species))
            continue;

        context.Species.Add(species);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exception details.
    }
}

The "context" instance lives just for the individual operation and will be disposed and re-created whether successful or failure. Attempting this with a module-scoped single DbContext won't work as the faulty, duplicate row will remain in the DbContext change tracker, poisoning it. You can explicitly remove poisoned pending rows from the DbContext by detaching them, but overall it is a good practice to avoid code that calls SaveChanges() multiple times.

THanks. The code was written that way to find the exact species that was called with a debugger point and the codeexists within a try catch block with the real code having an ending SaveChanges at the end of the parsed XML file. The question boils down to what would make a EF Dbcontext not be able to find an item that exists in the database. The code is just the verification format of the problem.
